# How to download internet file locally in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling with a simple task of downloading a file locally. Can someone point me to a library and a sample code that download say [a file](https://fixturedownload.com/download/nba-2018-EasternStandardTime.csv) locally ?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at a package like [`http-wget`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-wget).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the most common packages for this purpose are `http-client`, `http-conduit`, `wreq`, and perhaps `req`.  All appear fairly well maintained.  The last three are actually based on `http-client` and just try to provide a slightly friendlier interface (`http-conduit` and `wreq`) or a more type-safe interface (`req`).  For the simple task of downloading a file, there's not much to choose between the first three.  The fourth (`req`) is maybe overkill because it's somewhat more complicated to use, though I've included an example at the end.

To use `http-client` for HTTPS connections, you need to install both the `http-client` and `http-client-tls` packages.  Sample code to retrieve and save a downloaded file would look like this:

```
import Network.HTTP.Client          -- package http-client
import Network.HTTP.Client.TLS      -- package http-client-tls
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

main = do
  -- create a connection manager
  manager <- newManager tlsManagerSettings
  -- create the request
  request <- parseRequest "https://www.google.com/robots.txt"
  -- make the request
  r <- httpLbs request manager
  -- get the contents (as a lazy ByteString)
  let contents = responseBody r
  -- write it to a local file
  BL.writeFile "myfile.txt" contents
```

For `http-conduit`, the code is similar.  It just drops the requirement for using an explicit "manager" and allows you to construct a request directly from a text string using the `OverloadedStrings` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Simple           -- package http-conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

main = do
  -- make the requeset
  r <- httpLBS "https://www.google.com/robots.txt"
  -- get the contents (as a lazy ByteString)
  let contents = getResponseBody r
  -- write it to a local file
  BL.writeFile "myfile.txt" contents
```

The `wreq` package uses the `lens` package and has a pretty clean interface:

```
import Network.Wreq                  -- package wreq
import Control.Lens                  -- package lens
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

main = do
  -- make a requeset
  r <- get "https://www.google.com/robots.txt"
  -- get the contents (as a lazy ByteString)
  let contents = r ^. responseBody
  -- write it to a local file
  BL.writeFile "myfile.txt" contents
```

The `req` package has a different design philosophy which makes its main request call look a fair bit more complicated:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Req               -- package req
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

main = do
  -- make a requeset
  r <- runReq defaultHttpConfig $
    req GET (https "www.google.com" /: "robots.txt")
        NoReqBody lbsResponse mempty
  -- get the contents (as a lazy ByteString)
  let contents = responseBody r
  -- write it to a local file
  BL.writeFile "myfile.txt" contents
```